# want alert box to appear if number of buttons selected is less than acquired

Tags: javascript, button, grid, alert

I have a grid of buttons which the user can select. What happens is the user enters in the text box the number of buttons they want to select and then they select those buttons in the grid. For example if the user types in "2" in the text box and selects "2" buttons and then tries to select a third, then an alert box appears stating that user is beyond limit please deselect a button.

Now what I want to know is how do I code it so that if user selects less number of buttons than in the text box, then an alert message appears stating to select more buttons?

Thanks

Code in jsfiddle: click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UNgta/1/)

Comment: When should this "select more buttons" alert appear? Other than the buttons you're talking about, do you plan to add a "Submit" or "Continue" button for the user to indicate that they've finishing making their selection? Or...?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order not to be showing an alert every time the user selects a button and it happens to be less than the amount of buttons he/she selected, you'll want to add some sort of submit button and ONLY have a script check the circumstances when they click it.

```
<form onsubmit="validate.submit(); return false;">
 <textarea id="input"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Simple enough, correct? Lets add `DIV` for where the buttons appear.

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="validate.submit(); return false;">
 <textarea id="input"></textarea> <br />
 <div id="buttons"></div> <hr />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now lets setup the JavaScript Functionality.

```
window.validate = ({
  config: {
    min: 1,  // Minimum amount of buttons allowed.
    max: 10  // Maximum amount of buttons allowed.
  },

  data: {
    state: 0,
    input: null,
    buttons: null,
    form: null
  },

  validate: function(refer) {
    // Refer is the amount of check boxes checked.

    if(refer < this.config.min)
        {
          alert("You checked to little!");
        }
    else if(refer > this.config.max)
        {
          alert("You checked to much!");
        }
    else
        {
          alert("You checked JUST right!");
        }
  },

  submit: function() {
    if(this.data.state === 1)
        {
          var refers = this.data.form.val,
              refer = 1;

          if(Object.prototype.toString.call(refers) === "[object Array]")
              {
                refer = refers.length;
              }

          this.validation(refer);
           return refer;
        }
    else
        {
          this.data.state = 0;

          try {
            var q = this.data.input.value;

             // Use Number object incase of cases where numbers have non-digit,
             // characters, like Infinity, NaN, 1e+10, ect.
            if(new Number(q).valueOf() === 0 && q.match(/\D/)) { throw new Error(); }
             q = eval(q);

            if(q > this.config.max)
                {
                  alert("We cannot process that many buttons!");
                }
            else if(q < this.config.min)
                {
                  alert("You must have at least " + this.config.min + " buttons!");
                }
            else
                {
                  q = Math.abs(q); // Negative to positive integer.
                                   // Textarea validation complete!

                  var html = "";

                  for(var i=q; i>0; i--)
                      {
                        html = html + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"val\" />";
                      }

                  this.data.buttons.innerHTML = html;
                  this.data.state = 1;
                }
          } catch(e) {
            alert("You didn't enter a valid Number!");
          }
        }
  },

  setup: function() {
    window.onload = (function() {
      validate.data.form = document.getElementById("form");
      validate.data.input = document.getElementById("input");
      validate.data.buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
    });

    delete this.setup;
     return this;
  }
}).setup();
```

This was a quick a dirty example. You might have a few errors, for I didn't test it. Good luck! :D